# How to read an certain line from text file with UWP app?

Tags: uwp

How do I read for example only the second line from text file containing of four lines located on the Windows Phone SD card or internal storage with UWP app coded in Visual C#?

Does internal storage mean the same as Computer\Windows phone\Phone in Explorer?

Comment: can you share some of your code? What exactly is the challenge? What issues are you encountering?

Answer (score 2):

Since there are not a lot of details in your question I will assume the file you need is deployed with the application.

```
public async Task<string> ReadLine(int lineIndex)
{
    var path = @"test.txt";
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
    var lines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
    if (lines.Count >= lineIndex + 1)
    {
        return line[lineIndex];
    }
    else
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

If the file is not deployed with the app, change the folder property to another one from here: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current. (LocalFolder, TempFolder, RoamingFolder)

Answer (score -1):

Helllo, reading and writing files from phone memory is quite easy. Have a look at the following sample. I demonstrated how you can write a text file to IsolatedStorage and then read it. Hovewer if you want to read or write from SD card things are not so bright there. Have a look on MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card#querying-the-contents-of-the-sd-card).

```
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (isoStore.FileExists("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestFile.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                {
                    var rows = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    await new MessageDialog(rows[1]).ShowAsync(); //This is second row because the arrays are zero based

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestFile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("1. Hello from first row");
                    writer.WriteLine("2. Hello from second row");
                    writer.WriteLine("3. Hello from third row");
                    writer.WriteLine("4. Hello from fourth row");
                    writer.WriteLine("5. Hello from fifth row");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: down-voted because issues with the code-sample provided. IsolatedStorage is a WP8 -Silverlight concept that should not be used anymore. Intead use ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. Also the way to read rows is sub-optimal. There are specialized methods to read individual lines. Splitting on "\r\n" is not recommended

Comment: Please provide some specialized methods for reading individual lines.